# How to sum cell in every nth row, for 3 sets of values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Every week I have a daily production tally that i want to sum. Its in the same format every day, so I want to tally the production figures for each particular product so that i can put it in a summary sheet.

> [image: Blockquote]

Theres an example of what it might look like.
I want to add the figure for Production for every day, for a week, but for simplicity sake, lets add 3 values.   So Id want to sum July 31 aug 1, aug2,  then aug3 aug4 aug5, etc.

Edited  to include what output should be

> [image]

Second Edit,

Heres an image with a simpler example and excpected output[image]

Comment: [Perhaps just use SUMPRODUCT](https://exceljet.net/formula/sum-if-one-criteria-multiple-columns) based on the codes in the leftmost column?

Comment: It might help if you could post the images of the source and the desired result with visible row numbers and column ids.

Comment: Let me put something together with row numbers to make it clearer. Will update in a few

Comment: @BigBen  I tried sumproduct, and I can add the first range, but once I drag the formula down, It doesnt adjust for the whole week. i get for example, A1,A2,A3; then A2,A3,A4, then A3,A4,A5. When I want, A1,A2,A3; then A4,A5,A6 etc

Comment: Looks like you could just use SUMIFS based on your example output.